# Using AsyncTask in Service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

Is that a normal practice of using AsyncTask in Service (not IntentService). Or is it better to create background thread in another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that a normal practice of using AsyncTask in Service

No. The point of `AsyncTask` is to be able to do some work on the main application thread after the background work is completed. Services rarely, if ever, need to do work on the main application thread.

> Or is it better to create background thread in another way?

Yes: `new Thread()` would be a strong candidate as a straight-up replacement for `AsyncTask`. In other cases, some form of thread pool might make sense.

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted this. He answered the questions directly and accurately. AsyncTask, while would WORK, it isn't best practice. Use your own thread to do background work. Possibly even your own implementations of HandlerThread + Handler to handle work cleanly if it's a lot of serial tasks needing to be executed..

Comment: This is an accurate answer. Does not deserve a down vote.

Comment: Another point to add is that the intention of using a Service is for long running actions (suppose we are streaming music in the background, we are downloading large data, we are uploading large data) so that's when you'd avoid using an AsyncTask. Using an AsyncTask is for short lived operations, nothing heavy weight and lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

No, an AsyncTask is designed to run some short lived work in a background thread away from the UI thread. It has callbacks that allows it to modify the UI thread once it is completed.

If you need a separate thread in a service, create a thread using `new Thread()`