# Get AsyncTask status when re-opening application

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Currently I have a `AsyncTask` that gets called within my `RecyclerView.Adapter`, in it I'm downloading a file from a url and the progress is being displayed within my `ViewHolder` here is how my `AsyncTask` looks:

```
public class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int positionnumber;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        String pathreference = f_url[0] + ",";

        positionnumber = Integer.parseInt(f_url[0]);
        isDownloading.set(positionnumber, true);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[1]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return null;
            }

            if (a.equals("one")) {
                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/" + setDownloadedName + ".mp4");


                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();
                pathreference = pathreference + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + setDownloadedName + ".mp4";
                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return pathreference;
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

        prog = progress[0];

        Log.d("Progress", progress[0]);
        bars.get(positionnumber).setProgress_(Float.parseFloat(progress[0]));
        float p = bars.get(positionnumber).getProgress_();
        if (p % 1 == 0)
            notifyItemChanged(positionnumber);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        String[] split = file_url.split(",");
        int index1 = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);

        try {

            videoHolderClass.get(index1).setImage(imgres[0]);
            bars.get(index1).setProgress_(0);
            manager.insertVideoPath(index1 + "", split[1]);
            RecyclerVideoAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(index1);
            isDownloading.set(index1, false);
            Log.d("done", "filesaved");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(c, "Network Error..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            prog = "";
            networkFailed = "yes";
            videoHolderClass.get(index1).setImage(imgres[1]);
            bars.get(index1).setProgress_(0);
            RecyclerVideoAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(index1);
            isDownloading.set(index1, false);

        }
    }
}
```

The `RecyclerView` is within a fragment and the fragment is populated in a `Activity` - `ViewPager`.

Now, whenever I close the Activity or go to a new Activity and return, the progress is not shown anymore.

I have seen that people do the following:

```
if(mtask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
    // My AsyncTask is done and onPostExecute was called
}
```

but the problem is that the `AsyncTask` is in my `Adapter`, so I can't reference to it in my fragment.

---

**My question:**

Can someone please explain to me what the correct way is to see if `AsyncTask` is running and update the progress when Activity is re-created?

Comment: I think you can take a look at "android foreground service". Foreground service will not killed even user close the app. So your async task should be execute under foreground service and every time your activity start you can connect to service to get the status of the download or the progress.

Comment: i think viewpager's OnCreateView() call again async task with some kind of id toggle.

Comment: @vsatkh I just read this SO post that contradicts your approach - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38468455/8199772

Comment: @ClassA  It's long story about AsyncTask but the discussion is correct and only focus on using AsyncTask. It does not mean using service is a bad practice. There was a comment below mention about large file (from your code you download mp4, a video might be huge). So best practice using AsyncTask to perform short execution and using Thread Handler with Service or IntentService to run a long task. The reason I recommend using foreground service together with thread or AsyncTask is because I saw you're potential download a large.

Comment: @ClassA Also there were a few thing, for AsyncTask you need to be careful onPostExecute, as you app be crash if view was destroy. Another thing if you allow multiple download you might need a queue otherwise it will slow down network and user will experience a poor network traffic on the other app. Last one is the limitation of background task on Android 8 where it can be killed if user leave the app, of course if user opt-in to do so.

Comment: @vsatkh I have provided a answer on how I accomplished what I wanted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I KNOW THIS IS NOT THE "CORRECT" WAY OF DOING IT***, but I have managed to figure out a work-around and it works for what I want to achieve.

---

I decided to use `SharedPreferences` to check if the file is being downloaded or not. In my `onPreExecute` I did the following:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        SharedPreferences sharePrefss = c.getSharedPreferences("busyDownloading", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharePrefss.edit();
        editor.putString("isItBusy", "yes");
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Above I store a `String` called "isItBusy" and I set it to yes.

Then in `onPostExecute` I change `SharedPreferences` to:

```
SharedPreferences sharePrefss = c.getSharedPreferences("busyDownloading", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharePrefss.edit();
            editor.putString("isItBusy", "no");
            editor.apply();
```

In my `Activity` I do the following when the user press the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SharedPreferences sharePrefs = getSharedPreferences("busyDownloading", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String getSharedUser = sharePrefs.getString("isItBusy", "");
    if (getSharedUser.equals("yes")){
        // AsyncTask - onPostExecute was not called = moveTaskToBack
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }else {
        //AsyncTask - onPostExecute was called and application can be destroyed
        finish();
    }
}
```

By doing the above I now know if the file is still busy downloading or not and handle the back button accordingly.

---

The next issue was to handle rotation of the device, because when the device is rotated the `Activity` is destroyed and created again.

To fix this the first thing I did is to retain the fragment state by adding `setRetainInstance(true);` to my fragments `onCreateView`. Then in my manifest I added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to my `Activity`.

Doing this solved the rotation issue.

---

The last issue that @vsatkh mentioned was to queue the downloads. The files that I'm downloading is not that big (about 2-5MB at most). So I decided to only enable one download at a time, by also checking the `SharedPreferences` as shown below:

```
holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {

            SharedPreferences sharePrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("busyDownloading", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String getSharedUser = sharePrefs.getString("isItBusy", "");
            if (getSharedUser.equals("yes")){
                Toast.makeText(c, "You can only download one file at a time...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {
             DownloadFileFromURL p = new DownloadFileFromURL();
             p.execute(pos + "", downloadLink);

            }

        }
    });
```

Not all the method I used (like checking if files already exist) are included above, only the ones relevant to the question I asked.